# Prevent .net ide from jumping to current executing line when breaking

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, ide

When breaking in .net, it always jumps to the currently executing line.  I would rather just use shortcuts to bring up the stack and go there manually if that's what I want to do.

I could have sworn I saw an option to prevent it from doing this once upon a time but I can't seem to find it anywhere now.  Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# Keyboard layout, when I hit a breakpoint (or halt with Ctrl+Alt+PauseBreak), I usually press Ctrl+Alt+C to bring up the CallStack window, then up/down keys and press enter to navigate the call stack.

With VS2010 I've seen some weird results (options) after installing various plugins and 3rd party components at different work places...

Comment: Thanks.  I meant though that I knew how to do that and would rather do it manually than have the ide automatically jump to the code that's on top of the call stack.  Best I can tell though it looks like it's not possible.  Not sure where I saw the option before but I'm thinking now it must have been in a different application.